# Was burning/disposing of furniture a common act during the Iranian Revolution?

Tags: islam, iran

I thought for sure I learned this in school, but I can't find any reference to it online. The basic idea I remember is that for one reason or another the Ayatollah and his followers believed furniture to be evil, or at least un-Islamic, and convinced his countrymen to burn all the furniture they owned. I searched Google trying to find explanations of the phenomenon (wanting to know the basis of the belief) and found not even a reference to it having happened.

Did it happen? Did something similar happen (just chairs and not tables, for instance)? Is my recollection mistaken?

Comment: given the winter weather and the lack of fuel supply during the period, it's quite likely people would have burned furniture for heating and made up stories about how they did it out of piety later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- It is revolution and in a revolution chaos raises, when chaos raises it is absolutely possible [cars or furniture or even people burn](http://www.fardanews.com/fa/news/100956/%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D8%B9%DA%A9%D8%B3%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84%DB%8C).

2- The Ayatollah (Ruhollah Khomeini) and his followers did not believe furniture to be evil, but they believed luxury furniture was the symbol of aristocratic life (Persian: Zendegi-e Taghoti [زندگی طاغوتی](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%BA%D9%88%D8%AA)). However, This doctrine did not last much longer and vanished by passing time.

3- There was not any [Fatva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatwa) which issued on evilness of furniture.

4- Revolutionaries aimed banks and cinemas frequently and burnt their furniture. because banks considered as symbol of capitalism and cinemas as symbol of lechery and [hegemony of western culture](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%85_%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%86%DA%AF%DB%8C).

5- Conclusion: Burning/disposing of furniture was a common act during the Iranian Revolution, because in chaos of a revolution it is absolutely possible that people rush to some houses or banks or shops or... and burn the furniture of them. From beginning of Islamic Republic of Iran until now there have been a lot of [Hezbollahis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hezbollah_of_Iran) who used best furniture what remained from Shah's time or they bought them from west. For example, you can see the photos of banquets of presidents of Iran for foreign guests in [Sa'dabad Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%27dabad_Palace).